# Forgetten to click space bar on burg install

Tags: burg

I got some info about burg [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/beautiful-boot-menu-burg-ubuntu/) and I wanted to install it to my pc. I used the following commands to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

Unfortunately I have forgotten to hit space bar while selecting my boot HD. Help me select my boot HD.

Answer (score 1):

If you forget to do something during installation:

```
dpkg-reconfigure <package name>
```

In your case:

```
dpkg-reconfigure burg
```

---

On a side note:

[BURG is probably dead](https://code.launchpad.net/burg) and [GRUB 2 can do themes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534689) while keeping your system stable.